# Auth::check always return null

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, routes

I'm trying to make a button appear when a user log in. If the user isn't log in, the button wouldn't appear on the page. So the first thing i need is to determine if the user has log in or not. The problem is, The Auth::check() keeps returning null. I've done research that we should put the route inside the Auth middleware, but in doing so, users would have to log in to see the page and i don't want that. I want the users to be able to see the page without login and when they do login, a button will appear on the same page.

**Component**

```
 <button v-if="showBtnDelete==true" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

 <script>
      getUserType(){
            axios.get('api/gallery/getUserType').then(res=>{
            this.showBtnDelete = res.data;});
        },
 </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getUserType()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        return 'true';
    }else{
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],function(){
Route::get('/add-image', function () {return view('layouts.master');});
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('home');
});

Route::get('{path?}', function () {
return view('layouts.master');
})->where('path', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Auth::guard('api')->check()`? Just replace `api` with the guard you want to check (I used that one because you are making an ajax call from axios)

Comment: Try a “dd()” before the return and let us know what it says

Answer (score 1):

> guard API or web

```
Auth::guard('api')->check();


Auth::guard('web')->check()
```

Comment: it returns false both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem. The problem is that your route is not protected by the middleware group web.
That means it will not be able to retrieve the session of the current user so the Auth facade will always return null.
Add middleware('web') to the route accessing the method (code) and you will be able to retrieve the current user if logged in.